# Angular&rxjs testing performance of API with multiple requests

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to check response time for multiple requests sent to API, than display it on chart with help of chart.js I already have done it, but I am not sure if I am doing it right, because responses could not come and my code is adding point on chart only when client receive equal amount of responses that user entered.

here is function responsible for sending request to API and returning response time and data weight:

```
testRequests(numOfRequests, numOfRecords, db): Subject<any> {

const subject = new Subject();

for (let i = 1; i <= numOfRequests; i++) {
  const start_time = performance.now();
  this.http.get(BASE_URL + DATABASE + db + LIMIT + numOfRecords, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe((response) => {
    subject.next({
      time: performance.now() - start_time,
      weight: response.headers.get('Content-Length')
    });
  });
}

return subject;

}
```

and here is func, that receives results and when it have same amount responses that user requested it adds point to chart:

```
makeTest(requestsAmount = 1, requestDB = 'aurora') {
const arrOfResults = [];
this.subscription = this.api.testRequests(requestsAmount, 5, requestDB).subscribe(
  result => {
    arrOfResults.push(result);
    if (arrOfResults.length === +requestsAmount) {
      this.lineChartData[0].data.push(arrOfResults[arrOfResults.length - 1].time);
      this.lineChartData[1].data.push(arrOfResults[arrOfResults.length - 1].weight * arrOfResults.length / 1024);
      this.lineChartLabels.push(arrOfResults.length + ' - ' + (requestDB === 'aurora' ? 'Aurora' : 'DynamoDB'));
      this.chart.chart.update();
    }
  },
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log('completed')
);

}
```

as I heard that there is no guarantee that request will produce response, and responses can get lost, I would like to improve my code, so its generate point on chart in case there are some responses missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribe` method is not called when there is an unhandled error. You need to use a `catch` listener for error events.

The below example catches all errors and converts them into a `null` value. Now `subscribe` will receive either a response or `null`.

```
 this.http.get(BASE_URL + DATABASE + db + LIMIT + numOfRecords, {observe: 'response'})
       .catch((error, resp) => null)
       .subscribe((response) => {
             subject.next({
                  time: performance.now() - start_time,
                  weight: response ? response.headers.get('Content-Length') : 0
             });
       });
```

Comment: Tried, and I get a typescript error: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>'.